# Do what `which` does in bash but in C

Tags: c, linux, path, posix

What's a linux or posix C function to find the executable the same way Bash looks for an executable when you type it? I think `which` bash command does the same thing at least very similar. So if I give the function argument `"ls"` it returns "/bin/ls" for example looking into `$PATH` on the fly.

Comment: Do you know that `which` is written in C? Do you know that there are open source implementation of it? Have you inspected them?

Comment: There isn't a posix C function to find an executable in a list of directories: you have to write your own. Maybe you can call `which` with POSIX [`popen()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html)?

Comment: Well you should iterate through all directories in PATH until you find it, should be pretty easy to implement.

Comment: `which` is not a bash command, btw, it's a standalone executable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I examined the source code of the following commnads.
Both functions parse and search the environment variable PATH on their own.

- [which](https://carlowood.github.io/which/)

  ```
  char*
  extract_colon_unit (char const* string, int* p_index)
  ```
- [execlp](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/)

  ```
  static int
  __execvpe_common (const char *file, char *const argv[], char *const envp[],
                    bool exec_script)
  ```

I guess there is no C function to search for commands.

Comment: But writing one shouldn't be a problem